# fail to return result for all value in array

Tags: php

Hi the result for my code is:

```
array (size=1)
7 => string '0' (length=1)
```

i don't know why i have return just for last array value in $dist?! i need the results for all value in $dist so pleas can some one help me?

```
$dist     = array('1'=>'0','2'=>'1','3'=>'2','4'=>'3','5'=>'4','6'=>'5','7'=>'6');
foreach($dist as $key => $value)
{
    $day     = time() - (24 * 60 * 60 * $value);
    $pastday = time() - (24 * 60 * 60 * $value + 1);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as '" . $key . "' FROM profile_fields_plusmw3 WHERE banstart >= '" . $pastday . "' and banstart <= '" . $day . "' and pf_can_play_expire >= '".time()."'"; 
    $dayres = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($dayres);
}
var_dump($row);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you overwrite your variable in each loop. You have to put your results back into result array if you want to have all results available.

```
$dist = array('1'=>'0','2'=>'1','3'=>'2','4'=>'3','5'=>'4','6'=>'5','7'=>'6');
$rows = array();
foreach($dist as $key => $value) {
    // ...
    $rows[] = $db->sql_fetchrow($dayres);
}
var_dump($rows);
```